# Report Builder SQL parameters with multiple values and LIKE query statements

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0

I'm having an issue setting up my parameters to inject into a LIKE statement in my code.

For my parameters I have the following setup:

```
Q1 - PM-B2009M;
Q2 - PM-B2010M;
Q3 - PM-B2011M
```

Part of my code has:

```
WHERE

(WO.STA3N = @Site AND 
  (WO.WorkOrderNumber LIKE '%' +@Quarter+ '%')
```

Ideally I'd like to set it so that multiple parameter values can be selected and injected into the code instead of writing out:

```
(WO.WorkOrderNumber LIKE 'PM-B2006M%'    
    OR WorkOrderNumber LIKE 'PM-B2007M%'   
      OR WorkOrderNumber LIKE 'PM-B2008M%')
```

I tried to modify the parameter value statements themselves to include the OR but that didn't work either.

I'd appreciate any insight.